# Return sum of [column] and most recent value for [column] in the same query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need my sql query to return:

- One row for each `Data_Type` (regardless if data has been entered for that type)
- The sum of all Data for that Data_Type
- The most recent Data value for that Data_Type (sorted by `Date_Entered DESC`, then by `Data_ID DESC`)
- 0 for sum and most recent, if no Data exists for that Data_Type

Example:

```
Data_Type_ID   Data_Type
-------------------------------------
1              Height
2              Length
3              Weight
4              Width

Data_ID   Data_Type_ID   Data   Date_Entered
-------------------------------------
1         4              4      4/6/2016
2         1              8      4/7/2016
3         3              7      4/4/2016
4         3              5      4/7/2016
5         4              1      4/5/2016
6         1              12     4/5/2016
7         4              3      4/6/2016
```

I want to return:

```
Data_Type   Total   Most_Recent
-------------------------------------
Height      20      8
Length      0       0
Weight      12      5
Width       8       3
```

Right now, I have:

```
SELECT
      t.Data_Type
    , ISNULL(SUM(d.Data), 0) AS Total
    --, ISNULL(??, 0) AS Most_Recent
FROM
    Data_Type_Table t
LEFT JOIN
    Data_Table d ON t.Data_Type_ID = d.Data_Type_ID
GROUP BY
    t.Data_Type
```

This successfully returns one row for each Data_Type, with the sum of all Data values for that Data_Type and 0 if no values exist.  I'm not sure how to modify my query to add the most recent Data value for each Data_Type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use window functions: `ROW_NUMBER` and `SUM OVER`:

```
WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT
        dtt.*,
        dt.Data,
        Total = SUM(dt.Data) OVER(PARTITION BY dtt.Data_Type_ID),
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION by dtt.Data_Type_ID ORDER BY dt.Date_Entered DESC)
    FROM Data_Type_Table dtt
    LEFT JOIN Data_Table dt
        ON dt.Data_Type_ID = dtt.Data_Type_ID
)
SELECT
    Data_Type,
    Total = ISNULL(Total, 0),
    Most_Recent = ISNULL(Data, 0)
FROM CTE 
WHERE rn = 1
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ac23c/1/0)

Answer (score 2):

I would approach this using conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT t.Data_Type, COALESCE(SUM(d.Data), 0) AS Total,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 1 THEN d.data ELSE 0 END) as MostRecent
FROM Data_Type_Table t LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT d.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DataTypeId ORDER BY Date_Entered DESC) as seqnum
      FROM Data_Table d
     )
     ON t.Data_Type_ID = d.Data_Type_ID
GROUP BY t.Data_Type;
```